# How can I control image preload request?

Tags: javascript

I have a html markup. I need a DOM tree to rewrite image's src attribute.My code is as bellow...

```
var markup = '<img src="abc.jpg"/>';
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = markup; 
(rewrite logic here(div))
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

However when execute at the 3rd line a error request is send out.

***GET https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/abc.jpg 404 (Not Found)***

How can I control this image preload request? When I append the element into the document then send out.

I use  documentFragment as a test, it also have this problem.

```
var str ='<img src="abc.jpg"/>';
var range =document.createRange();
range.selectNodeContents(document.documentElement);
var fragment =range.createContextualFragment(str);
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? The request fires out as it should. Maybe you mean you want to delay the request, and/or never fire it at all?

Comment: is dose the src for `abc.jpg` point to where your image is located which in that case is likely should be in the same location where your page is?

Comment: Hi Mihalis, I want to delay the request. Because at the time when I execute this statement "div.innerHTML = markup; "the image's src attribute is not correct. I need handle a DOM tree to rewrite the uri.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple. Use createElement for the image too

If you use createElement on the image, you can assign an error handler to it

For example

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.onload=function() { // only add the image if found
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.appendChild(this);
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}
img.src="abc.gif";
```

or

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.onerror=function() {
  this.src="notfound.gif"; 
}
img.src="abc.gif"; 
div.appendChild(img);
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

If that is difficult because of complex html, perhaps you should replace the image src with a "loading.gif" and then change the src of the image after:

```
var imgs = document.getElementById('newDiv').getElementsByTagName("img");
for (var i=0;i<imgs.length;i++) {
  img = imgs[i];
  img.onerror = ....
  img.src=extractedImagesFromHtmlSnippet[i]
}
```

Comment: Hi mplungjan, thanks for your answer. The input markup can be complicated, not only a image tag but also has other document tags.How can I extract  the image from the markup and then set the img object into the markup?

Comment: The markup can be this kind:<div><span><img src="adc.jpg" class="rewriteuri helloworld_image"/></span></div>
 <div class="helloworld_text">Hello World!</div> Rewrite uri is indicator to indicate that this img's src attribute should be rewritten.

Comment: In jQuery you could add a $("#container img").live(...) but then I read this http://forum.jquery.com/topic/error-event-with-live - anyway see update